# UI Control positioning in Netbeans 6.8

Tags: java, netbeans6.8

i want to add Label,buttons,text box above another label in netbeans 6.8 ,how can i do so??

Comment: you look it up in the doc. not here

Comment: very basic try this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFr06ZKIpSM

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at those tutorials and the screencast:
http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/matisse.html

It's basically pure drag-and-drop.

Answer (score 0):

What your talking about isn't in fact NetBeans, its the [Swing Application Framework](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/swingappfr/). NetBeans just provides a GUI to make development with Swing easier. Check out the link above for more information.